# How can i add an onclick even in an image tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to make the textbox display a paragraph when i click the image based on what it displays on the dropbox but I've tried several methods and nothing works.

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
function Select(){
  var select = document.GetElementById("selection").value;
  if(select == "mission")
  {
    document.getElementById("Par").value = "Johnny Bravo";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("Par").value = "dadadadsa";
  }
}
</script>
<body>
  <p>Select any one:</p>
  <form>
     <select name = "dropdown" id="selection">1
        <option value = "Mission" selected>Mission</option>
        <option value = "Vision">Vision</option>
        <option value = "Goal">Goal</option>
     </select>
  </form>
  <img src="GC-CCS.jpg" alt="MissingImage" onclick="Select();"style="width:200px;height:200px;">
  <input type="text" id="Par" size="50">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. Firstly, you have typo in `GetElementById("selection")` (capital `G`) and secondly, you have to lower case the value as *"Mission" != "mission"*:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
function Select(){
  var select = document.getElementById("selection").value.toLowerCase();
  if(select == "mission"){
    document.getElementById("Par").value = "Johnny Bravo";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("Par").value = "dadadadsa";
  }
}
 </script>
<body>
  <p>Select any one:</p>
  <form>
    <select name = "dropdown" id="selection">1
      <option value = "Mission" selected>Mission</option>
      <option value = "Vision">Vision</option>
      <option value = "Goal">Goal</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <img src="GC-CCS.jpg" alt="MissingImage" onclick="Select();"style="width:200px;height:200px;">
  <input type="text" id="Par" size="50">
</body>
```